# JQuery validate | submitHandler

Tags: jquery

Есть некая форма, которая проверяется jquery Validate, но дело в том, что отправка происходит только по второму клику. Насколько понимаю по первому клику происходит проверка, по второму отправка.

Конструкция следующая, и мне нужен *именно такой* вариант.
Как сделать чтобы проверка\отправка происходила в один клик?

```
 submitHandler: function(){
     $("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert(this.id);
     });
}
```

Comment: Покажите весь код целиком.

Comment: @Eleferen Отредактировал, проверка формы проходит корректно

Comment: Какой смысл вот этого действия - `$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){` ?

Comment: @Igor , универсальный код отправки на формы,получаю айди кнопки, и по айди собираю нужные поля, их и отправляю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
    submitHandler: function(form){
        form.submit();
    }
```

---

Так, начинаю догадываться, что Вы хотите сделать.

Вы назначаете обработчик `click` после клика, который вызвал первую проверку (валидацию) и отправку формы.

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
});

$(formId).validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 17,
            maxlength: 17
        }
    },
    messages: {
        phone: {
            required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            minlength: "Телефон должен быть минимум 11 символов",
            maxlength: "Телефон должен быть максимум 11 символов"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(){
        // ... your code
    }
});
```